# Is it possible to make nonnull become part of C++ type system?

Tags: c++, null

`NULL` is the billion-dollar mistake but there is nothing in the type system of C++ to prevent it. However, C++ already has const-correctness so implementing `NULL`-correctness seems trivial:

- introduce a keyword, `__nonnull`, as a specifier in the same class as `const`, which can only be placed after the `*` in a declaration.
- All pointers obtained by `&` operator is `__nonnull`.
- A `__nonnull` pointer value or `const` reference can be automatically converted to a normal pointer, but not vice-versa without a cast. (`T *__nonnull` can be converted to `T *`, and `T *__nonnull &` can be converted to `T *const &`)
- Writable references of pointers cannot be automatically converted between normal and `__nonnull` (`T *__nonnull &` CANNOT be converted to `T *&`), i.e.

  ```
  int x;
  int *__nonnull p = &x;
  int *q = p; // OK
  int *const &r = p; // OK
  int *const *s = &p; // OK
  int *&t = p; // ERROR, don't want to assign NULL to t
  int **u = &p; // ERROR, don't want to assign NULL to *u
  ```
- `const_cast` can be used to cast a normal pointer to a `__nonnull` pointer, in which if the pointer is really `NULL`, the behaviour is undefined.
- Assigning a null-pointer constant `0`, `NULL` and `nullptr` to a `__nonnull` pointer variable is an error.
- `__nonnull` pointers cannot be default initialised, like a reference.
- Have a standard library function to convert a normal pointer to a `__nonnull` pointer, which throws an exception on `NULL`.
- An optional warning will be given by compiler for dereferencing normal pointers without `NULL` check, which the practice is going to be deprecated.

Is the above proposal viable? Are the above things enough for a `NULL`-safe type system?

Comment: Did you look at not_null in the gsl library? Here is one article about it: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/06/01/using-the-not_null-template.aspx

Comment: References already are non null pointers, with the restriction that you may not reassign them. Most of your suggested behaviours can be implemented with a `nonnull<T*>` wrapper, no language changes required.

Comment: The question would be "is there a good reason for a NULL-safe type system?" - NULL is there for a good reason.

Comment: This question would be handled better on [the ISO-C++ proposal forum](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals). Q&A is not an effective means for tempering a proposal.

Comment: @tofro And that good reason is? I can't think of any advantages `null` has over a proper option type.

Comment: "Billion dollar mistake" is very much exaggerated. It wasn't a mistake in the first place - because nobody had thought of any alternatives when the "mistake" was supposedly made.

Comment: @amon you can't store references in a container. You could use `std::reference_wrapper` though.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the above proposal viable?

No.

First, it doesn't work for user-defined types. Whereas `const` does. Even `volatile` does. And with lots of smart pointer types, having it work with user-defined types is kind of important.

Second, using `const_cast` to convert to `__notnull` is... silly.

Third, C++ is not C. If something is important enough to get a keyword in C++, then it's important enough to get a keyword that doesn't look terrible.

Fourth, this can be done adequately through a simple type. The C++ core guidelines support library provides `not_null`, which essentially has the properties you suggest. And, unlike `__notnull`, it works with user-defined smart pointers too (though not `unique_ptr`).

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work for user-defined types. The mechanism does not matter what type the pointer points to.

Comment: @MichaelTsang: Not pointers to user-defined types. User-defined types that *act like pointers*: `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, etc. Your mechanism does not allow me to declare `__notnull shared_ptr<T>`. Whereas `gsl::not_null<shared_ptr<T>>` works (though not `unique_ptr`).